# Controlling stepper motor using raspberry pi and Matlab

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi3, motordriver

We are trying to rotate stepper motor (Nema23 57HS22-A) in specific number of steps using raspberry pi 3 and digital stepping driver DM556 using Matlab.

We managed to rotate the stepper motor in specific number of steps (3000 steps in this code) with the following python code:

Pin 29 is connected to the PUL+ of the DM556 which rotate the stepper motor every time it changes from 'LOW' to 'HIGH'.
Pin 31 is connected to DIR+ which decide the direction of the stepper motor's rotation.
Pin 32 is connected to ENA+ which enable the stepper motor at 'LOW'.
PUL-,DIR-,ENA- connected to GND (not in the code).
this code will rotate the stepper motor 3000 steps to one side and 3000 steps to the other side in endless loop.

```
Import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(29,GPIO.out) // GPIO 5
GPIO.setup(31,GPIO.out) // GPIO 6
GPIO.setup(32,GPIO.out) // GPIO 12

GPIO.output(32.GPIO.LOW) 

While True:
    GPIO.output(31,GPIO.HIGH) 
    For i in range(0,3000): 
        GPIO.output(29,GPIO.HIGH)
        Time.sleep(0.0005) 
        GPIO.output(29,GPIO.LOW)
        Time.sleep(0.0005)
    GPIO.output(31,GPIO.LOW)
    For i in range(0,3000):
        GPIO.output(29,GPIO.HIGH)
        Time.sleep(0.0005) 
        GPIO.output(29,GPIO.LOW)
        Time.sleep(0.0005)
```

We try to convert this code to matlab and we wrote this code which didn't rotate the motor:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

rpi1 = raspi('192.168.67.187','pi','raspberry');

pul_x = 5;
dir_x = 6;
ena_x = 12;

configurePin(rpi1,pul_x,'DigitalOutput');
configurePin(rpi1,dir_x,'DigitalOutput');
configurePin(rpi1,ena_x,'DigitalOutput');

writeDigitalPin(rpi1,pul_x,1);
writeDigitalPin(rpi1,dir_x,0);
writeDigitalPin(rpi1,ena_x,0);


for i = 1:200
    writeDigitalPin(rpi1,pul_x,1);
    pause(0.001);
    writeDigitalPin(rpi1,pul_x,0);
    pause(0.001);
end
```

We succeed to rotate the stepper motor with this matlab code but without a specific number of steps:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

rpi1 = raspi('192.168.67.187','pi','raspberry');

pul_x = 5;
dir_x = 6;
ena_x = 12;

configurePin(rpi1,pul_x,'PWM');
configurePin(rpi1,dir_x,'DigitalOutput');
configurePin(rpi1,ena_x,'DigitalOutput');

writeDigitalPin(rpi1,dir_x,0);
writeDigitalPin(rpi1,ena_x,1);
writePWMDutyCycle(rpi1, pul_x, 0.5);
writePWMFrequency(rpi1, pul_x, 1000);

for i = 1:200
    writeDigitalPin(rpi1,ena_x,0);
end

writeDigitalPin(rpi1,ena_x,1);
```

We trying to fix the 2nd code to make the stepper motor move, but we'll be glad to hear any other suggestion to rotate the stepper motor in specific number of steps.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

We found that the second code we posted actually works, but the problem is that the command writeDigitalPin takes too much time (20 msec) and therefor the stepper motor moving too slow to see.
Is there any other function or way to reduce the time in order to make the motor run faster?

Answer (score 0):

To control a servo motor you can use servo obj and the writePosition() function available in Raspberry Pi supportpackage.

```
r = raspi;
servoControlPin = 29;
s = servo(r,servoControlPin);
for i = 1:3000
    position = (180*i)/3000
    writePosition(s,position);
end
```

Please refer the [doc page of servo](https://in.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypiio/ref/servo.html) to know more about how to configure minimum/maximum pulse duration.